# Cómo muestro los datos calculados en un ciclo While en un GUI sin interrumpir el ciclo while?

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando en Python 2.7 con un Raspberry 3, hice un programa que cuenta piezas mediante un sensor IR.  Además de contar piezas calcula el tiempo entre piezas, el tiempo total en funcionamiento, el tiempo promedio por pieza y otros datos.

Cómo presento los datos en tiempo real en una interfaz de usuario sin interrumplir el ciclo while que recibe la información del sensor IR?

Comment: usa un nuevo hilo...

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Deberás utilizar programación multi-hilo para resolver el [problema de productor-consumidor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_productor-consumidor) que planteas. Para ello necesitaras al menos 2 hilos de ejecución en paralelo: Uno que tenga el 'ciclo while' que actualice el valor de un objeto (productor), y otro que lea este objeto mostrando algo en pantalla (consumidor).

Dado que tu pregunta no presenta código, puedo darte una referencia en forma de pseudo-codigo para que te hagas una idea, y referencias para que puedas aprender más.

```
from threading import Thread

estado = {}

def async(fun):
    """
    Define un decorador para funciones asíncronas.
    :param fun:
    :return:
    """
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        t = Thread(target=fun, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    return decorator


@async
def sense_ir():
    """
    Ejecuta la logica de entrada y salida para actualizar el estado de un objeto visible desde fuera.
    El decorador async hace que llamar a esta función no bloquee el hilo de ejecución principal.
    :param fun:
    :return:
    """
    while True:
        # aquí tu lógica, recuerda interactuar con una variable global o algo para dejar los resultados
        estado['number'] = 1
        estado['shape'] = 'triangle'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # aqui la lógica del hilo de ejecución principal
    sense_ir()  # esta instrucción no bloquea (i.e. es asíncrona), pero gatilla el comportamiento de la función en otro hilo de ejecución
    # aqui coloca tu lógica que lea el objeto compartido entre ambos hilos
    while True:
        print('hay {} objetos'.format(estado['number']))
```

Ahora, la programación multihilo tiene tanto bondades como nuevos problemas, por ejemplo, debugear se hace mas complejo, si existen muchos hilos escribiendo y leyendo la misma variable, los valores compartidos pueden resultar en estados inconsistentes (data-races), hay que preocuparse de tener operaciones atómicas sobre estas variables, etc. En fin, te invito a permearte más de conocimientos de programación concurrente o multi-hilo; te dejo estos link, sin embargo ya sabiendo los términos que te presento podrás encontrar más información sin problema: https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/